# Abelian category equivalent to a non-abelian category

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

I was told that if we have an equivalence of categories $F : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ with $\mathcal{A}$ abelian, then it is not necessarily true that $\mathcal{B}$ is also abelian.

I would like to know if there are nice examples of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ which is equivalent to a non-abelian category $\mathcal{B}$.

Furthermore, are there any conditions over $F$ or $\mathcal{B}$ so that we have "$F : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is an equivalence and $\mathcal{A}$ is abelian implies $\mathcal{B}$ is abelian"?

Comment: This is a surprise for me. Never heard this before.. May be I don’t know what exactly is an equivalence of categories :D Have you tried to write down some examples of categories, equivalence of categories and see if you can cook up something... Sorry for the not so useful comment...

Comment: 6 up votes for such a comment is making me nervous :D..  I read the comment now, it sounds like a satirical comment.. This is not intended to be a satirical comment.. Please do not read it as a satirical comment...

Comment: Has the coronavirus infected the central nervous systems of so many of the honorable members of math overflow? This question is uninteresting. If your definition of abelian category is a category satisfying some caterogical property, then the answerr is trivially yes, exactly as "a group isomorphic to an abelian group is abelian". If your definition of an abelian category is a category *with additional structure* satisfying some property, then the question does not make any sense, because $\mathcal B$ is not given any structure. Bugs Bunny seems the only non-crazy person around.

Comment: @Joël Note that Bugs explicitly claims the answer could be *yes*, inconsistent with your options, which I think everyone else agrees about.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you were told is wrong, for we have the following:

**Proposition.** *If two categories are equivalent and one of them is abelian, then so is the other.*

A proof (and some related results) can be found in Satz 16.2.4 in H. Schubert, *Kategorien II,* Springer, 1970 (likewise in the English version [https://www.amazon.com/Categories-Horst-Schubert/dp/3642653669](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642653669), under the same numbering).

Comment: Just to make very clear: the proof is not difficult — it could be a slightly boring homework question in any course that introduces Abelian categories.  All the components of the definition of Abelian category are pretty straightforwardly invariant under equivalence of categories for all of the definitions of Abelian category I know.  If the OP has read some definition of Abelian category for which this *isn’t* straightforward, I’d be interested to hear what that definition is.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine :the first time I read the definition of an abelian category, it was as an $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched category with such-and-such properties, so the $\mathbf{Ab}$-enrichment was taken as additional structure in that definition (that was essentially because the documents I was reading wanted to prove some general stuff about $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched categories before going on to abelian ones). With this in mind, if you've never seen how the $\mathbf{Ab}$-enrichment actually follows from the properties of your abelian category, it's not obviously clear that it should be invariant

Comment: @Maxime: That’s the main definition I think of too; but even without realising that the enrichment is determined by the other properties (which I agree is not at all obvious), I think it’s pretty straightforward to see that Ab-enrichment transfers along équivalences of categories.  The only subtle aspect of this is having the confidence to read “invariant under equivalence” as something you can assert about a structure, not just a property.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a manifestly invariant definition of an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$. It is a category with finite limits and colimits such that:

1. (It is pointed) the map from the initial to the final object is an isomorphism; we denote by 0 any object which is both initial and final.
2. (It is semiadditive) the map $X \amalg Y \to X\times Y$, given on $X$ by components $(\mathrm{id}_X, X \to 0 \to Y)$ and on $Y$ by components $(Y \to 0\to X, \mathrm{id}_Y)$, is an equivalence. We denote by $X\oplus Y$ the coproduct or product, identified as above. This equivalence produces an abelian monoid structure on all hom sets, where addition arises from $X \to X\oplus X \stackrel{f\times g}{\to} Y\oplus Y \to Y$.
3. (It is additive) the shearing map $X\oplus X \to X\oplus X$, given by adding the identity map to the projection onto the first component followed by inclusion, is an equivalence. Equivalently, each hom-monoid has the property that it is group-like.
4. (first isomorphism theorem) if $f: A \to B$ is arbitrary, then the map $A/\mathrm{ker}(f) \to \mathrm{ker}(B \to B/A)$ is an isomorphism.

Being an abelian category is a property not structure.

Comment: Off course, but this is not the definition here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelian+category

Comment: And this is the only meaning I can possible give to the statement in question...

Comment: Just for reference: this is the definition in Freyd's *Abelian categories* (so hardly an obscure one :))

Comment: Note that 2. and 3. are actually consequences of 1. and 4.

Comment: How? What about the category of groups?

Comment: @Arrow 4 is not satisfied: A/ker(f) is the image but B/A is the quotient of B by the smallest normal subgroup containing the image of f (which need not be the image of f).

Comment: @DylanWilson ah, I stopped reading after "first isomorphism theorem" assuming it refers to the "usual one" in the categories of groups, rings etc.

Answer (score -8):

As a discerning dissenting voice, let me say that it might be true, depending on your definitions.

Take abelian $A$. Let $B:=A$ with forgotten enrichment in abelian groups. Then the identity functor is equivalence, but $B$ is not abelian because it is not even additive.

There are two definitions in play. The first is *abelian category*. The standard (ncatlab or Wikipedia) definition of abelian category asks for the category to be [pre-additive](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pre-additive+category), which requires enrichment in abelian groups that can be forgotten. An alternative definition, mentioned in other answers, is from Freyd's book: there abelian is an inherent property rather than an additional structure. This definition would make the statement false.

The second definition is  *non-abelian category*. There is no accepted definition. One possibility is to think of this as just a category. Together with the first definition of abelian category, this makes the statement true. An alternative is to think of a category that cannot be abelian (essentially the negative of the second definition). This choice would make the statement false.

Comment: "Dissenting voice", I think.

Comment: What is an equivalence between a category and a category enriched in abelian groups?

Comment: @Lennart Meier  It is just a category equivalence. $Hom(X,Y)\rightarrow Hom(FX,XY)$ is a bijection between a set and an abelian group.

Comment: @Robert Furber  Both

Comment: Well, if you make a wrong definition then you can prove all kinds of things...As we’re doing category theory here it shouldn’t be too controversial that there is no such thing as a bijection between a set and an abelian group, rather than with the underlying set of an abelian group. So you call $A$ abelian after forgetting the enrichment, but refuse to call $B$ abelian even though it admits a canonical enrichment-these choices aren’t consistent with each other.

Comment: The absurdity of this answer is clear if we say “Can an even number be equal to a non-even number? Take even $a$.  Let $b := a$, but we forget that it is even.” Just because we forget that a number is even doesn’t make it not even. Just because we forget that a category is abelian doesn’t make it not abelian.  When you forget the Abelianness, what you haven’t isn’t a non-Abelian category, it’s a category that hasn’t yet been equipped with Abelian structure, but could be.

Comment: I politely disagree and stand by my answer. I suggest that some of those, making snippy comments and downvoting my answer, go to Wikipedia and ncatlab and change the definition there to Freyd's definition. If this gets accepted by the Wikipedia cabal, I will withdraw my answer.

Comment: "Being abelian" is property-like structure (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property#generalization_to_categories_and_higher_categories) that is preserved by any equivalence. One could go through this step by step. Is having a zero object preserved by equivalence? Check. Is having biproducts preserved by equivalence? Check. And so on. Now it's quite true that such property-like structure is not preserved by arbitrary functors. But functors that are equivalences? Certainly.

Comment: @BugsBunny Another try: if you require that an abelian category $A$ be given along with its canonical enrichment in abelian groups, then there is *no such thing* as a functor from $A$ to a category $B$ whose hom-objects are mere sets. You've tried to make a definition as "a functor out of the underlying ordinary category of $A$", but by your own definition the underlying ordinary category of $A$ is not abelian. Thus the question becomes meaningless, rather than having a positive answer.

Comment: On further reflection: what Bugs might mean is that, for example, there is more than one way to endow an object $Z$ with the structure of being a product of objects $X, Y$ (using different choices of projection maps), so that Person A's notion of how $Z$ is a product doesn't match Person B's notion. But that doesn't matter: we say that $F$ preserves products if the canonical map $F(X \times Y) \to FX \times FY$ is an isomorphism. With this understanding of what preservation of (property-like) categorical structure means, all equivalences preserve zero objects, biproducts, and so on.

Comment: @BugsBunny: My objection to this answer is nothing to do with the specific definition of Abelian category used by Wikipedia/nlab/Peter Freyd; nor is it anything to do with Abelian categories being property-like structure.  My objection is that you interpret the OP’s “…a non-Abelian category” (which is, admittedly, a slightly unclear phrase) as being “a category not currently considered as an Abelian category”.  I think this is clearly not the standard mathematical practice; compare analogous questions like “Can a non-even number be equal to an even one”, [cont’d]

Comment: [cont’d from prev] …or “Can a group be bijective with a set that is not a group?”.  I think the typical mathematician’s response to this latter question would be to first note that “a set that’s not a group” is slightly bad writing, but to take it as meaning “…a set that *can’t* be given a group structure”, and as such answer with “No: given a bijection from (the underlying set of) a group $G$ to some other set $X$, we can transfer the structure from $G$ to $X$.”  I think your interpretation of the question is not what OP meant, and not how most mathematicians would understand it.

Comment: Actually, I don't find "non-abelian category" unclear. I can't think of a realistic situation where I would ever use that phrase, except maybe in response to a beginner question, but a category either is abelian or it isn't, and there's only one way (up to canonical iso's, etc.) that a category can be an abelian category. It's not in the same league as equipping a set with a group structure.

Comment: Well, that is a completely different objection to my answer. This deserves clarification in the answer.

Comment: @BugsBunny The definition from e.g. Dylan's answer is equivalent to the one you're using! The point is that although many books define an abelian category to be a pre-additive category satisfying various extra properties, which makes it seem as an Ab-enrichment has to be specified as part of the data of an abelian category, this is in fact not the case.

Comment: The point is that the Ab-enrichment is uniquely determined by the fact, which is implies by the axioms of an abelian category, that the sum of two arrows $f$ and $g$ from $X$ to $Y$ is the composite $X \to X \oplus X \to Y \oplus Y \to Y$ where the middle arrow is $f \oplus g$, and the other two arrows come from $\oplus$ being a categorical biproduct.

Comment: @DanPetersen +1. Yes, that is precisely the point (and essentially the point made by Dylan, of course).

Comment: @Dan Petersen I understand your point completely. Now try to understand mine. Think of a unital associative ring. Translated to this case, your point is that unital is inherent property. My point would be that taking "unital" out of the signature changes many things, for instance, its representation theory or model theory. Going back to the original question, model theory of abelian categories will probably depend on whether enrichment is part of the signature.

Comment: @BugsBunny The model theory is independent for all definitions I know: a functor of semiadditive categories has an enriched structure iff it preserves (co)products, and such a structure is unique

Comment: @BugsBunny Then how would you answer the following question? "Suppose $A$ is a unital ring, $B$ a not necessarily unital ring, $A \cong B$ an isomorphism of not necessarily unital rings. Must $B$ be unital?"

Comment: @Dan Peterson Excellent example! If "unital" means a ring with 1, then yes. If "unital" means a ring with 1 in signature, then no.

Comment: Even if @BugsBunny's point of view presented is non-standard, it is by no means ridiculous, and certainly not deserving of all these downvotes. If anything, I applaud BugsBunny's openness of mind to step outside the definitions imposed by the majority for the sake of evaluating what may have led the OP to his question.

Comment: @Patriot I have tried to understand Bugs’ explanations and I still cannot see how one can consistently claim the question just discussed is anything other than meaningless or negative. If a unit is part of the signature, then it’s meaningless to ask whether $B$ “is unital.” If not, then the answer is that $B$ must be unital. Bugs, do you really think that the model theory of rings which happen to admit a unit and homomorphisms which preserve the unit is different from that of rings with a unit in their theory’s signature? How? The categories of models are *isomorphic*!

Comment: @Kevi Carlson  The map $A\rightarrow A \oplus B$ is a homomorphism in one and not in another.

Comment: @BugsBunny Well, no. If you will kindly look a bit more closely, I specified that homomorphisms must preserve the unit. Under the analogy, you'll recall we're discussing equivalences between abelian and "non-abelian" categories, which automatically preserve the biproducts that we're analogizing here to the unit in a ring.